# Circular flowchart alignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I´m trying to create a circular flowchart using the **smartdiagram** package  but I can't get the nodes properly aligned.

My code:

```
\smartdiagramset{border color=none,set color list={blue!40!,blue!40!,blue!40!,blue!40!,blue!40!},uniform arrow color=true,}
 \smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{Edit, pdf\LaTeX, Bib\TeX/ biber, make\-index,Test}
```

[image]

Is there a way to alter the alignment so that for example "Element" is on top and the other elements are arranged symmetrical?

Comment: There's no parameter that lets you specify the starting angle.  You'd need to patch the implementation, or draw it "manually" as a linked series of nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I draw it manually and it just works fine for me ;.) \begin{tikzpicture}

\def \n {4}   % number of Elements
\def \radius {5cm}
\def \margin {20} % margin 

\foreach \x/\y in {0/a,1/b,2/c,3/d} {\x \y,  % place here all names of the elements 
 \node[block] at ({90 + 360/ \n  * \x)}:\radius) {$\y$};
\draw[->, >=latex, ultra thick] ( {90 + 360/ \n  * \x + \margin}:\radius) arc ({90 + 360/ \n  * \x + \margin}:{90 + 360/ \n  * ( \x  + 1)- \margin}:\radius);
};
\end{tikzpicture}

Comment: @M.Miller I recommend you to convert the solution you got according to this comment, into an answer, so you can help somebody that may have the same problem, and to let people value your work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's apparently a limitation of the package, and the only workaround is given in comments.